# How to Remove the Logout Button and store the session permanently FBSDK IOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, session, fbsdk

I am creating an app in which user can Sign in using Facebook. I am fetching user info like profile picture Username etc. Now when i tap on Login with facebook button FB ask for permission i am loged in. but then there is Logout Button displaying at the same place as LoginWithFacebook button was. I want to Remove the logout button because i do not want the user to log out. I want to store the session and use it all the way long until app is unintsalled because I do not want the user to login each time when he opens the app.
    This is my code so far

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var btnFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ivUserProfileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
var strFirstName: String!
var strLastName: String!
var strPictureURL: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureFacebook()
}

func configureFacebook()
{
    btnFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
    btnFacebook.delegate =  self
}

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        //fetching first and last name
        self.strFirstName = (result.objectForKey("first_name") as? String)!
        self.strLastName = (result.objectForKey("last_name") as? String)!
        self.strPictureURL = (result.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as? String)!
        // contactinating first and last name
        self.lblName.text = "Welcome, \(self.strFirstName) \(self.strLastName)"
        // assinging image
        self.ivUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.strPictureURL)!)!)
        }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    //for logging out from facebook
    loginManager.logOut()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide logout button after login via facebook by using below code like,

```
 if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
 {
       self.btnFacebook.hidden = true
 }
 else
 {
       self.btnFacebook.hidden = false
 }
```

NOTE: You need to check this after every login and logout in your code so that you can easily maintain that button log.

For Session, Write this in viewDidLoad of LoginController to get user info,

```
    self.btnFacebook.delegate = self
    self.btnFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]

    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getUserProfile:", name: FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

    if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        if(accessToken != nil)
        {

            let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
            req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if(error == nil)
                {
                    let userInfo = result as AnyObject
                    if let _ = userInfo.valueForKey("email") as? NSString
                    {
                        // Extract user info here
                        let userDic : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: userInfo as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
                        print(userDic)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // Logout if you want or display error message
                       // let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
                       // loginManager.logOut()
                    }
                }

            })
        }
    }
```

Call this observer method,

```
func getUserProfile(notification : NSNotification)
{
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    if(accessToken != nil)
    {

        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil)
            {
                let userInfo = result as AnyObject
                if let _ = userInfo.valueForKey("email") as? NSString
                {
                    let userDic : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: userInfo as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
                    print(userDic)
                }
                else
                {
                    // logout or error message 
                    //let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
                    //loginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks it worked. and can you guide me about the session ? how can i store and reuse the session ?

Comment: I think you need to check session for getting info about already login user via FB right? Then you can do it manually by using this accessToken

Comment: i do not want the user to login each time the app is opened so how can i acheive this can you explain by example ? thanks

Comment: There is no direct way to get session in FBSDK but you can use FBSDKAccessToken as a session and it will work as session. Once you login via FB you will get accessToken anywhere throughout the application so by using this accessToken you can perform task which you want to do by using session. You can write it like, `if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
            if(accessToken != nil)
            { // Session ON } else { // Session OFF } }`

Comment: how can i ensure that session never expires ? i mean i just do not want re login untill the app is unistalled

Comment: It will not expired until you will log out it so you can check this condition in viewDidLoad of your login controller and make user as a login user every time.

Comment: i did that but when i close the app and run it again i am again promted with the login  button. where i should be getting the profile picture and username directly :-(

Comment: im sorry its still same when i close and rerun my app it still ask for login what i want is that when 2nd time i run my app it should direcytly give me my profile pic and welcome msg (using first name and last name)

Comment: I already did that in my app so can you check my edited answer again. Where you will get user details but for profile pic you need to write different logic

Comment: i cehcked the answer but for some reason its not working for me. I was wondering that is the simulator causing thr problem ? i mean if i run it on a actuall device will the app logn automaticaly with the help of SSO ?

Comment: What kind of error is there? Have you reset the simulator?

Comment: there is no error but after logging in i close the app from simulator and re run in from there and i am promted with login button although i shoud be going directly without login

Comment: can you share your peoject please ?

Comment: sry but i can't. Have you check after removing app from background?

Answer (score 1):

Add fb login button variable manually to your view controller

```
let fbLoginBtn = FBSDKLoginButton()
```

In your viewDidLoad

```
view.addSubView(fbLoginBtn)
```

Handle hidden state of login btn by check `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` has value or not

And you can logout programmatically by `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()`

Comment: tried this as well but logout button is still there i do not want logout button any where         `// creating login bUtton closure  
    let btnFacebook : FBSDKLoginButton = {  
        var button = FBSDKLoginButton()  
        button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];   
        return button  
        
    }()`

Comment: Then you can hide or show login/logout button manually depend on your login state by check Access Token? :D

Comment: yeah did that now logout button is gone but i want to store my session so that user should not login each time how can i do that ?

Comment: Sessions are stored automatically when you logged in with FBSDK
As I said above, `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil` means there's still session stored.

Comment: i undesrtand that now thanks. but why is it happening that i get login button each time i run the app in the simulator ? is it becuase simlator does not have an Fb app installed ?