# how to set swrevealController after my login viewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app in which I have login page and dashboard page in login page user can login with facebook,after login I navigate the user to dashboard everything works fine till now

But in dashboard I am going to add side menu (by using SWRevealViewcontroller) If I give swrevealviewcontroller as intialView It works but I could not see the login page

First I have to bring login page then it should move to dashboard(which contains side menu item). Here I am using two navigationControllers one is to login and another one is for swrevealViewcontroller

I don't know how to move from login page to dashboard (which contains side menu item) now

This is my app delegate

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        print("at delegate")
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("kUserLogin")
        {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let root:UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealView")
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = root
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else
        {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as UIViewController
            let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

            return  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,

                                                                          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions) || true
    }
```

this is my loginbutton function

```
 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!,didCompleteWithResult result : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)

    {
         print("come to ")
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name,picture.type(large),gender,email"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            print("come to print")
            let strName: String = (result.objectForKey("name") as? String)!
            print("before getting token")
           var token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            print(token)
            print("after getting token")
            print(result)
            let Gender : String = (result.objectForKey("gender") as? String)!
            let Id = (result.objectForKey("id") as? String)!
             let deviceId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString
          let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
            print(UUID)
            var DeviceId = deviceId
            print(DeviceId)
            print(Id)
            print(Gender)
             print(strName)
           var strEmail : String
            if ((result.objectForKey("email") as? String) != nil){
                strEmail = (result.objectForKey("email") as? String)!
            }else {
                strEmail = "not available"
            }
            //let strEmail: String = (result.objectForKey("email") as? String)!
            var userID = result["id"] as! NSString
            var facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
           // print(strEmail)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://projects.svirtzone.com/wified/api/authentication.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "username=\(strName)&email=\(strEmail)&action=auth&pic=\(facebookProfileUrl)&dob=1989/05/05&logintype=Facebook&gender=\(Gender)&device_type=Mac&facebookid=\(Id)&agerange=15&deviceid=\(deviceId)&accesstoken=\(token)"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
                if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                }

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            }
            task.resume()
                              }

        if(error != nil){

            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
       print("before main view")
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if !defaults.boolForKey("kUserLogin")
        {
            print("inside if***")
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "kUserLogin")
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "kUserLogin")
        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealView") as UIViewController
        let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
        app.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        app.window?.rootViewController = nav
        app.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()     

    }
```

this is my main viewController(I set this with swrevealViewController)  here I have side menu item "Menu" this Item is disabling now

```
 @IBOutlet var Menu: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        Menu.target = self.revealViewController()
        Menu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())    

    }
```

this is my google signIn code in appDelegate

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
            withError error: NSError!) {

    if (error == nil) {
       print("at delegate5")
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        var imageURL = ""
        if user.profile.hasImage {
            imageURL = user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(100).absoluteString
        }

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ToggleAuthUINotification",
            object: nil,
            userInfo: ["statusText": "Signed in user:\n\(fullName)","email" : email, "imageURL" : imageURL])
         print( imageURL)
       let postString = "username=\(fullName)&email=\(email)&action=auth&pic=\(imageURL)&dob=1989/05/05&logintype=Google&gender=female&device_type=Mac&facebookid=no&agerange=15&deviceid=not available&accesstoken=\(idToken)"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://projects.svirtzone.com/wified/api/authentication.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()

     } else {

        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            "ToggleAuthUINotification", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if !defaults.boolForKey("kUserLogin")
        {
            print("inside if***")
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "kUserLogin")
        }
               }
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "kUserLogin")
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealView") as UIViewController
    let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
    app.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    app.window?.rootViewController = nav
    app.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()   

}
```

Can any one help me please ?

Comment: Create a navigation controller object .Then assign that SWRevealViewcontroller to that object . then set this as you want to use (left and right view of SWRevealViewcontroller)

Comment: Thank you so much can you say me briefly I am new to this development @sourav

Comment: var nvController: UINavigationController!
nvController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SplashVC())
        let leftMenuViewController = SideMenuVC()
        let sideMenuViewController = SWRevealViewController(contentViewController: nvController, leftMenuViewController: leftMenuViewController, rightMenuViewController: nil)
        SWRevealViewController.menuPreferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
(something like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I hope it would be helpful!!!

After the login successfully set flag value in LoginViewController

```
 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 if !defaults.boolForKey("kUserLogin")
 {
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "kUserLogin")
 }
```

When You log out set the flag value and make Login Screen as root

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "kUserLogin")
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
app.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
app.window?.rootViewController = nav
app.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Step-2 Set Rootviewcontroller as SVrevealviewcontroller

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("kUserLogin")
        {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let root:UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController")
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = root
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
        else
        {
            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
            let nav:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: initialViewControlleripad)
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much user is not getting log out in my app then how can I do this @Sanjeet verma

Comment: Remove the part of Logout and keep the same code in Appdelegate and Loginviewcontroller

Comment: You just set the SVRevealController as a RootViewController

Comment: kUserLogin means What do you mention ? @Sanjeet verma

Comment: it's Just a key,my code will work suppose if user login then it will redirect to SVRevealcontroller and without log out when it run the application again then it will redirect to SVRevealviewController,and when the user logout then it will redirect to LoginViewcontroller.I hope make sense

Comment: I am new to this development really I don't know how to  get kUserLogin It shows error when I am using that like ( Use of unresolved identifier 'kUserLogin')  @Sanjeet verma

Comment: Heartly Thank you so much it works very well but i have an Item on top left  to open my side menu it is disabling I could not click the button but I can see it as just shadow(but I can trag and see the side menu) and I added your logout code after your login code continuously can you help me@Sanjeet verma

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy can you show some code it would be helpful for trace the exact problem.?

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy Comment out the logout code and add this one let root = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController")
        self.presentViewController(root!, animated: true, completion: nil) Because after login you have to moveout on dashboard. and if you want at some places user logout then add logout code on that place.  i hope make sense

Comment: Thank you so much it works but while successfully logged in the facebook  log out button comes and goes can i hide it @ Sanjeet verma

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy Yes you can hide it after getting the successfully logged in with facebook ,when you are getting the user info after that you can hide the button  button.hidden = true i hope it will work as you want.

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341398/how-to-remove-the-logout-button-and-store-the-session-permanently-fbsdk-ios-usin it would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much all answers are useful @ Sanjeet verma

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy I'm glad to help You,Happy Coding:)

Comment: I have another doubt too let root = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController") self.presentViewController(root!, animated: true, completion: nil)               I cannot add this line to my appDelegatebecause (in signIn function) my google sign in finished in appDelegate only so I have to add this line in my appDelegate but I cannot how can I do this Is there any changes on this line @ Sanjeet verma

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy Yes you have to do same process as you did for login,

Comment: but while adding this line to my appDelegat it shows error like "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'storyboard' "how to fix it @Sanjeet verma

Comment: After the Google Sign you have to redirect the rootviewcontroller so Keep this code where google sign in finish
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let root:UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController")
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = root
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: If I add this line in my appDelegate it shows the errors like "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'UIStoryboard.Type'" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'mainStoryboardIpad'" I added this line at signIn function how to fix it @Sanjeet verma

Comment: Can You show code for google signing what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I have added my google sigin code at last please check it at last of the sigin function I added your code you said first@ Sanjeet verma

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy Comment out that code which is written at last and put the code this one and i assume google sign code execute from Appdelegate file and if possible then you do message on my personal Skypeid sanjeet.kumar767
 let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) let root:UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RootViewController") self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) self.window?.rootViewController = root self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() i hope make sense.